# Dynamically add fields to NutchDocument

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.12 with Elastic Search and I would like to add a field dynamically to `NutchDocument`.

Currently, I can add static field values to `NutchDocument` and able to index it to Elastic Search.

Here's the code snippet of my indexing filter:

```
public class CustomIndexFilter implements IndexingFilter {

    private Configuration conf;

    public Configuration getConf() {
        return conf;
    }

    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    @Override
    public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, Parse parse, Text url, CrawlDatum datum, Inlinks inlinks) {
        String content = parse.getText();
        doc.add("pageLength", content.length());
        return doc;
    }
}
```

I think that `NutchDocument` is created after parsing. So, field values need to supplied before that (don't know where should I supply this). Seeking a workaround for this.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest a workaround for this. You can use Nutch REST api to create custom configuration with custom options for the crawl run. And then read that particular configuration inside your custom indexer plugin. This way you can control what is being indexed by setting the fields in ***NutchDocument*** after reading them from conf. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The NutchDocument is created during the indexing step and, as you found out, modified by IndexingFilters. The latter often use metadata coming from the parsing but the fields themselves are created mainly by the IndexingFilters (some are created by the main indexing code). There is a number of plugins that allow you to generated fields based on the configuration e.g. index-metadata or index-static.